# Where is the fuel filter(s) located on a 2006 VW Golf?

Tags: vw, golf, fuel-filter

I have an occasionally stuttering 2006 VW Golf (Mk4) with 160k miles that I believe is caused by a partially blocked fuel filter.

Are there multiple fuel filters (i.e.- one in the fuel tank and one in the engine compartment) or a single fuel filter and where are they located?

**UPDATE**
It has the non-turbo 2.0L 4 cylinder (BEV) engine

Comment: which motor is this? the 2.0T or the VR6?

Comment: @NoCarrier update question, it's 2.0L, no turbo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just one fuel filter.

The diagram on this page shows it located off to the side of the fuel tank  (it is marked with a 7):
http://www.wagenstad.com/index.php?modid=224&page=2-201-40[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get a frame of reference of the image.  Is the filter near the fuel tank or is it in the engine compartment?

Comment: Near the fuel tank.   Item number 1 is the line that goes to the top of the fuel tank.

Answer (score 1):

if you have golf mk4 it's located under passages back door even with center of window about 12" in. I have a 3 line fuel filter 2 from tank 1 to engine.make sure you order correct one.  the push clips are the trip :)ᙚᵐⁱᒻᵉ ¨̮